# FormatNumber replace Decimal with Comma using SpreadsheetGear dll

Tags: vb.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I want to apply Format Number to a Excel Cell from VB.net using SpreadsheetGear dll  as below

This number **2,22,222.00** needs to convert to **2.22.222,00**

My work:

```
worksheet.Range(NumberRange).NumberFormat = "[=0]0;###,###.00"
```

I am applying this format for English language, similar way I want number format to convert  and display in the cell.

Comment: Sorry it may not be portugal but I want thousand seperator as "." and decimal seperator as "," using number format symbol something like "[=0]0;###,###.00" from vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("PT").NumberFormat
```

Comment: I want thousand seperator as "." and decimal seperator as "," using number format symbol something like "[=0]0;###,###.00" from vb.net